# Is it possible to define the standard function notation $f(x)=y$ in terms of an arbitrary relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, first-order-logic

$%PREAMBLE
\newcommand{\FITCH}[1]{\begin{array}{rlr}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\FC}[1]{\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}} %FirstColumn
\newcommand{\SC}[1]{\begin{array}{c|l}#1\end{array}} %SecondColumn
\newcommand{\TC}[1]{\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}} %ThirdColumn
\newcommand{\SUBPROOF}{\\[-0.27em]} %adjusts line spacing slightly
$
In elementary set theory (as far as I know) $f$ is a function if, and only if $f$ is a relation: $\forall x[x \in f \rightarrow \exists y \exists z[x = \langle y,z \rangle]]$, and
$f$ is many-one: $\forall x \forall y \forall z[\langle x,y \rangle \in f \land \langle x,z \rangle \in f \rightarrow y=z]$

Now, in maths, it is very unusual to see the notation $\langle x,y \rangle \in f$ being used, with the notation $f(x)=y$ being preferred. However, this type of notation doesn't work for any relation. Specifically, it only works if the $y$ is unique for any given $x$. As an example, taking an relation $A=\{ \langle 1,2 \rangle, \langle 1,1 \rangle \}$, using the notation $A(1) = 2$ and $A(1) = 1$, we can conclude that $1=2$, which is an absurd. This notation only works if the relation is a function. So we can define the notation as:

$$f(x)=y \leftrightarrow f \text{ is a function } \land \langle x,y \rangle \in f$$

Which is valid.

However it would be very interesting if we could define a notation $f(x)$ for any relation, and then prove that it's unique only for functions, and then be able to use it accordingly. A definition like:
$$f(x) \leftrightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in f$$

is not really valid, since y is free but only appears on one side of the definition. We could define it like:
$$f(x)_y \leftrightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in f$$

Which seems valid. However, it doesn't tell us how to "remove" it to use the unique value $f(x)$, or even that $f(x)$ is a variable. We could try:

$$f(x)=y \leftrightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in f$$

However, that leads us right back to $1=2$.

So my question is, is it possible for us to define this type of notation for an arbitrary relation, and then prove that $f(x)=y \leftrightarrow \langle x,y \rangle \in f$ if, and only if, $f$ is a function?
Or is it necessary to embed the function status of $f$ in the definition?

---

Edit: My question states:

> [...] So we can define the notation as:
>
> $$f(x)=y \leftrightarrow f \text{ is a function } \land \langle x,y \rangle \in f$$
>
> Which is valid.

**It is not**. After making a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3972692/830362) to discuss the dubiousness of this (type of) definition, it is now clear that its validity would imply that every set is a function, which quoting [*Z.A.Q.*'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3978116/830362):

> Needless to say, this latter statement is very much not a theorem of any reasonable set theory.

The Q&A goes in more details for why this is the case. As such, **the above definition is not consistent with set-theory and should not be used**. Despite that, [Noah's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3878845/830362) is still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a set of ordered pairs. Let $dom(R)=\{x: \exists y(\langle x,y\rangle\in R)\}$. There is a natural function with domain $dom(R)$ which captures the behavior of $R$: $$\gamma_R: x\mapsto\{y: \langle x,y\rangle\in R\}.$$ The relation $R$ is a function iff $f_R(x)$ is a singleton for every $x\in dom(R)$, and so for $f$ a function we can think of "$f(x)=y$" as a shorthand for "$\gamma_f(x)=\{y\}$."